# Is every computation either symbolic computation or numerical computation?

Tags: paradigms

Is every computation either symbolic computation or numerical computation? Or, are there methods that are neither one nor the other (and also not a hybrid of the two).

Answer (score -1):

1. Numerical computation is a kind of symbolic computation as numbers are type of symbols.
2. Weighting on a scale could be seen as computation and it wouldn't use any symbols, maybe we could call it analog computation?
3. You can compute "by eye", "rough guess" - organoleptic computation?
4. You can also divine, I don't know how to name it.